# Making predictions in Logistic regression in R

Tags: r, probability, logistic

Can anyone please let me know, what does a logistic regression model predict?
For example, there are 2 variables. This may not be very appropriate example but it will clarify my question as follows:

```
Survived: Yes/No (binary variable)
Age (continuous variable)
```

While building the model in R, as far as I am aware, we never specify what is a success or failure `(p and 1-p)`.
Final model looks like `log (p/1-p) = a+bx`, but I never defined what would be p (success). The p or success for me, may be Yes or it may be No.
So when the model is generated what will it predict, Yes or No

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can relabel your classes as 1 and 0 or TRUE and FALSE, now the model will do it the way you expect.

If those are not the labels, well, I would try to guess it. You can try to see the prediction for an obvious "yes" and an obvious "no" and see what happens